# Consuming web service data into DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, web-services, architecture

I have created a website that has a `store` table of our company stores.  The `store` table data will be populated from data it receives via web service.  It will have to add new stores, mark stores closed that have been closed, and mark stores as open that have been reopened.

How do I populate this table with the web service?

1) Have some (cron) script that consumes the web service and syncs the data with the stores table?

2) Build this in to the app itself?  So that on app start, it syncs the data?  Then maybe somehow modify my model to sync data after every 10 minutes of a find (not really sure how this would work)?

3) Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with having a cron job. That would keep the population of the data separate from your application that uses the data. Also, it would mean you can keep your data up to date, even if your application goes offline. Finally, the data could potentially be used by a different application as well? If this is the case, it wouldn't make much sense to tie the population of the data to one of the applications that uses the data.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a database? Depending on what you're doing, it may be more practical to just talk to the Web service directly.